# Linking files when publishing a project

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project

I have a project that I wish to publish. currently, I hardcode some reference files (.json,txt, and .ico) to be used in my project, which reside in a folder on my desktop for testing purposes. now that I feel I'm close to a version 1.0 release I want to migrate my resources to a applications folder upon install. basically want to create these files when the app is installed.

2 big questions I have is how to reference to the application folder that doesn't exist yet, and how do I publish the setup project.

I have the setup project installed for VS2019, and followed a quick and brief blog on how to use it. but I haven't found out how to publish that setup project. I can publish my project with my actual code in it, but I cannot publish the setup project.

below is a screenshot of the setup project. and i will add screenshot of my settings for the reference file.
[image]
[image]

Comment: use relative paths rather than absolute ones or if you really need to use the desktop, what doesnt make sense in my opinion use something like the Enviroment namespace string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

Comment: i dont need the desktop. im expecting the default app folder. but how do i access these folders

Answer (score 0):

Add the files into subfolder of your project and in the options part in Visual studio set that files will be copied to "debug"/"release" folder.

You will have an output folder with all what you needs and can be shippable.

Comment: i will give it a go. where is the options you speak of. having hard time locating. also I cannot publish my installer setup for some reason.